# Are LdapQuery elements additive?

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm trying to run a search using Springs LdapQuery, and the behavior is not exactly what I was expecting. My gut instinct was that the more filters I provided, the smaller the working data set would be. Instead, it seems like the filters act independently of each other, and then those various working sets munged together before being returned, often resulting in the following error "[LDAP: error code 11 - Administrative Limit Exceeded]"

Here is a sanitized version of my search:

```
public List<OurUser> search(String nameSearchString, String city) {

        ldapTemplate.setDefaultCountLimit(100);//return up to 100 users
        LdapQuery query = query()
                .searchScope(SearchScope.ONELEVEL)
                .base("ou=People")
                .where("objectclass").is("inetOrgPerson")
                .and(query().
                                where("userStatus").is("Active")
                                .and("userEmployer").is("OurCompany")
                                .and("ou").is(city)
                )
                .and(query().where("cn").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("sn").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("givenName").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("primaryEmail").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("someUID").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("employeeId").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                                .or("someOtherUID").like(nameSearchString + "*")
                );


        List<OurUser> users = ldapTemplate.search(query, ourUserContextMapper);
        return users;

    }
```

Let's assume that the city search criteria is always populated (how about "Los Angeles"). The namesSearchString can vary since it is the value users are really searching for. When we have several characters ("STEW"), it runs as expected, but with only one or two we see the above mentioned error ("S"). That error partially makes sense, because looking for someone who has an "S" in any of those fields is going to retrieve a lot of matches across the entire org.... but in my head with the addition of the other query params, the addition of the "city" restriction would automatically shrink that list down to well under 100 people *before* apply the name/sn/etc query to it.

This makes me think I'm missing something here, or that I'm making a mistake trying to compare sql predicate handling to ldap.

So, the root of my question is:
1) What am I missing about the way the predicates are combined?
2) How (if it's possible) can I force the query to restrict by city first, and then apply the secondary "name" filter criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the error message. Note that it does not state "Size limit exceeded" but rather "Administrative Limit Exceeded", which means something else entirely. "Administrative Limit Exceeded" typically refers to a setting called "lookthrough limit", which - if you think about it - makes sense in this case.

The problem needs to be addressed on the LDAP server, either by changing the lookthrough limit, or by forcing the search space smaller, kind of like you are hinting at in your second question. My best bet would be to make sure that the most important search fields (in this case: `userEmployer` and/or `ou`) are indexed. That should force the server to apply those filters first, thus sufficiently limiting the number of items that the system needs to look through.